# Ethernet connection loses upstream UDP and TCP packets but downstream UDP packets are fine

Tags: networking, ethernet, tcp, udp

2 of my PCs are connected to my router like so:

Both PCs' ethernet cables -> Switch -> ethernet cable -> ethernet socket -> ethernet cable from socket -> switch -> ethernet cable to socket -> ethernet socket -> ethernet cable -> Router (Asus RT-AX92U)

All the ethernet cables are at least Cat-5e (1 gbps). All switches are unmanaged.

Every once in a while (maybe once every 2 hours or so?) this is what I get when I ping my router:

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

When this happens, I notice that I can still hear everyone perfectly fine in the Discord voice call throughout the timed out period, but they cannot hear me at all. I also get updates to other characters in the online game I play, just that the game will not register my own character's commands until the timed out period ends.

BOTH PCs always fail in this same manner at the same time.

This somehow makes me feel like incoming UDP packets keep coming through fine and it's just TCP packets or upstream UDP packets that do not? Which means the issue is anything upstream doesn't work (since TCP requires upstream ACKs I believe).

But this baffles me as to why this happens, I have never experienced anything like this where ethernet failed me in this weird way where downstream UDP packets still work perfectly fine. And I have no idea how to easily debug this (eg. connect straight to router, connect just to first switch) since I cannot easily replicate this issue and I cannot physically access some of these wires as they are inside my walls.

What is causing this and what do people recommend I do to fix this? Is there a specialist ethernet testing device I can use that will easily and consistently tell me exactly where this is failing? Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Comment: Just for a start, are there any 100Mbps Ethernet links involved or are all links 1Gbps? (The two have significant differences in the way bidirectional transmission is done – 10/100Mbps Ethernet has separate up/down pairs, 1Gbps doesn't – so e.g. a failure of one wire pair would have different results depending on the link speed.)

Comment: Are any of the switches 'managed' (i.e. do they have their own IP addresses) or are they all unmanaged? Being able to ping a switch would make it easier to narrow the problem down. (Often managed switches even have a rudimentary "cable test" function...)

Comment: @u1686_grawity thanks for that, addressed both comments as an edit on the original question.

Comment: You say the cables are Cat5e, but that in itself doesn't guarantee that 1Gbps will always be negotiated between devices (whether due to sub-spec cable, or due to damaged wire pairs, or damaged connectors, or manual speed settings...) It would be useful to check the actual links as reported by the PCs/routers/switches (Windows shows the link speed in Get-NetAdapter, switches often have a distinct LED color, etc).

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for that I can confirm running `Get-NetAdapter` gives link speed `1 Gbps`. That should be all the way to the router right?

Comment: No, it's only all the way to the switch. (Switches are the actual "Ethernet-connecting equipment" so to speak; routers are mainly "IP networking" equipment.) So there's an Ethernet link from PC to switch A, another from switch A to switch B, and then another from switch B to router['s builtin switch] – each of those links could be running at a different speed. (Which also means, unfortunately, if you don't have access to the switches, then there's no Ethernet testing device that could help you – all it would test is the link to the nearest switch but could not test all the way to the router.)

Comment: I have access to every switch and wire in the ecosystem (except for the ones behind a socket). But it's not quickly apparent to me if a wire is 1 Gbps or not and I cannot move my PC around to each wire either (or bring every wire to the PC for that matter). Can a testing device help me here?

Comment: In theory yes, but anything more than the typical "continuity test and not much more" tester costs a lot... (Though there certainly are testers that would show you that and everything.) Do your switches have distinct LEDs for 100M vs 1G link mode? Most switches have that (either separate LEDs or distinct colors or something), and that shows what mode is _currently_ being in use, which is actually more interesting than what the wire would be technically capable of... Though this is still mostly just for the sake of chasing one specific theory.

Comment: Just checked. The switch connecting directly to my PC doesn't have separate LEDs (but we can establish that that is 1 Gbps due to `Get-NetAdapter`). The other switch supports green and amber (<1 Gbps) lights and all are green. This means it's `1 Gbps` all the way from my PC to my router.

Comment: @u1686_grawity By any chance could you share your theory if you don't mind?